# Equivalent formulas give different results in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

One of my friends asked me why simple equivalent formulas get different results. Excuse me that the code is a bit long but the interesting part is just line 99 and 100. Here is the [formulas](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21031944/Matlab/1.pdf) and the [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21031944/Matlab/program1.m).
I checked the code. The problem is where `f = 1`. 
The problem is line 99 and 100. It takes about 10 s to run the code.
Thanks for any guide or comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. It is just because of round off errors. What you have commented out has some round off errors which makes `fplus~=1`, so:

```
E = log( (1 - 1") / 1) >= log(eps) >= -36.0437.
```

while the real value should be:

```
E = log( (1 - 1) / 1) = log(0) = -Inf
```

Comment: So here the simplified form is better. Dose it matter `log` show imaginary part? Its also for rounding error.

Comment: @Abolfazl in your code, both `fminus` and `fplus` are positive. so there is no imaginary part. And when calculating log, round-off errors only have effect on some special values, that is numbers approximately equal to zero or one(where you should use `log1p`).